# Intrinsic Height Issue in row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, row, overflow

I want to have three children in a row.

1. First child on the top.
2. Second child will have dynamic height according to the data in a column
3. Third child needs to be in center of regarding the height of the second child.

I was using Intrinsic height to achieve this but when the second size increased with data it gave overflow issue. Because it wasn't allowing the column in 2nd child to take as many height it needed. Any alternate solution for intrinsic height?

Any help would be great! The design I want to achieve is attached.[image: This is the design required]

Comment: Can you share a minimal amount of code so that we can understand the problem better?

Comment: I just need adjustment in the alignment. For that I think there is no required code. You can simply consider
Row(
children: [
FirstChild(),
Column(),(//dynamic height for column)
ThirdChild()
]
)

Answer (score 0):

Recently Flutter released this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Si5XJ_IocEs

Since you mentioned in the comments that your code can be considered a simple Row widget, I think the video has the answer to your problem.

Comment: I already mentioned intrinsic height is not working.. It works till a limit of center widget height after that it gives overflow error on center widget